# vba search through a folder and select files by name

Tags: file, vba, selection

I've got lots of files in a folder structered with names like:

"prof102122013@10.18.41.csv"

where the "02122013" bit is the date - 02/12/2013. Some of them have been made on the same day. I'd like to create a file that takes all of the workbooks that were made on the same day and put them all in one big file. So far I am struggling to get the selectivity to open a day-specific file. Does anyone have any idea what kind of code can help me with this?

Edit: Solved, thanks for the help, all! Here was the code that worked for me:

```
 folder_location = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

i2 = 0

strFile = Dir(folder_location & "\")

'looping through to find the right file names and putting them all in an array
While strFile <> ""
    If Right(strFile, 3) = "csv" Then
                file_to_analyse = Split(strFile, "@")
                If Right(file_to_analyse(0), 8) = date_we_want_to_analyse_on Then
                    found_files_to_analyse(i2) = strFile
                    i2 = i2 + 1
                End If
            End If
    strFile = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: Try `FileSystemObject` to read and write file. You can use `FSO` to search for files and folders too. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Can you provide a list of example file names? I think you can get what you want using the `FileSystemObject` as @PankajJaju says and combine that with the `RegExp` library to find the date for each file name (you will find an "edit" link underneath your question which will allow you to add in the examples).

Comment: Cheers guys! I used `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` and that worked for finding the folder, then a variations of Peekay's answer below using: `While strFile <> "" If Right(strFile, 3) = "csv" Then file_to_analyse = Split(strFile, "@") If Right(file_to_analyse(0), 8) = date_we_want_to_analyse_on Then found_files_to_analyse(i2) = strFile i2 = i2 + 1 End If End If strFile = Dir Wend` Thanks for your help, I appreciate it! (Edit: I'll write the code in my question section 'cuz I can't format it into a nice looking block in these comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to consolidate files on the basis of file saved date or on the basis of the name of the file. A file named with yesterday's date can be saved today and will bear today's date. I guess you would have to parse the name of the file and apply logic around the date (in the file name) in a do while loop till all the files in the directory are searched for the condition. If the condition is met, you copy the opened file into a worksheet in your file. If the condition is not met, the file is skipped. Following might help

```
For each date which needs to be consolidated, do the following in a loop or an in a user prompted message box where the user inputs the date. You also need to chose whether you want the consolidation to happen in the workbook from where you are launching the macro or a separately opened workbook. The code below assumes you are consolidating in the same workbook.

Path = Path of the directory in which the files are stored

Flname = Dir(Path & "*.csv")

Do While Flname <> "" 

If ' file check Condition' Then
    Filecheckname = True  ' Checks if file follows the naming conventions desired
Else
    Filecheckname = False
End If

If Filecheckname Then
    FlDate = getDate(Flname)     ' extracts the date from the file name
Else
    GoTo Errorhandler ' If there is an error, then the macro stops with a message to the user
End If

If FlDate<> Date Then

    flsskpd = flsskpd + 1       ' If the date criteria is not met, the file is skipped with an increment to the fileskipped counter
    Flname = Dir()
Else

     Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Flname, ReadOnly:=True

'Code to Copy into consolidated workbook (ThisWorkbook)
filesmoved = filesmoved + 1
     Flname = Dir()
End if

Loop

Message to user about how many files skipped and consolidated. 

Prompt user whether to continue to the next date consolidation, if yes, continue or take the new date as an input and repeat the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want VBA to "search" for a file/folder in a directory, I think you need to use something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Enum xlSearchMode
    xlFilesOnly = 0
    xlFoldersOnly = 1
    xlFilesAndFolders = 2
End Enum
Function SearchInDirectory(FName As String, Optional FoName As String, Optional SearchMode As xlSearchMode = xlFilesOnly, Optional ExactMatch As Boolean = True) As Variant
    'By Abdallah Khaled Ali El-Yaddak
    'Returns an array of strings with files/folders matching what you are searching for.
    'If nothing is found, it returns an array of one empty string element.
    '-------------'
    'FName (String): The file/folder to look for
    '[FoName] (String): The directory to search in, if omitted, CurDir will be used.
    '[SreachMode] (xlSearchMode): xlFilesOnly (default) = Look for files only | xlFoldersOnly = Look for folders only | xlFilesAndFolders = Look for both
    '[Exactmatch] (Boolean): True (default) = Look only for this string (case insenstive) | False = Sreach for any files/folders that includes this string in their name
    Dim FSO As Object, File As Object, Folder As Object, Fnames() As String, i As Long, SubNames As Variant, SubFolder As Object
    If FoName = "" Then FoName = CurDir
    If Right(FoName, 1) <> "\" Then FoName = FoName & "\"
    ReDim Fnames(1 To 1) As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FoName)
    If SearchMode = xlFilesOnly Or SearchMode = xlFilesAndFolders Then
        For Each File In FSO.GetFolder(Folder).Files
            If (ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name = FName) Or _
                    (Not ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name Like "*" & FName & "*") Then
                Fnames(UBound(Fnames)) = File.Path
                ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) + 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If SearchMode = xlFoldersOnly Or SearchMode = xlFilesAndFolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In FSO.GetFolder(Folder).subFolders
            If (ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name = FName) Or _
                    (Not ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name Like "*" & FName & "*") Then
                Fnames(UBound(Fnames)) = SubFolder.Path
                ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) + 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    For Each SubFolder In FSO.GetFolder(Folder).subFolders
        SubNames = SearchInDirectory(FName, SubFolder.Path, SearchMode, ExactMatch)
        If SubNames(LBound(SubNames)) <> "" Then
            For i = LBound(SubNames) To UBound(SubNames)
                Fnames(UBound(Fnames)) = SubNames(i)
                ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) + 1)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    If UBound(Fnames) > 1 Then ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) - 1)
    SearchInDirectory = Fnames
End Function
```

To test, you need something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a As Variant, i As Long
    a = SearchInDirectory(date_we_want_to_analyse_on, folder_location, xlFilesOnly, Flase)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        Debug.Print a(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

1. This solution doesn't work on MAC (tested only on windows)
2. Searching will take longer for larger directories (The number of files/folders inside)